# Delete Directories smaller than x

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

How can I delete Directories which are smaller than, say, 1000 KB?

I already have a file list from the command:

```
du -sk * | sort -n > sort.txt
```

but I don't know how to proceed.

---

Update:

```
du -sk */ | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }; { if($1 < 1000) printf "%s\0",$0 }' | sort -nrz | hexdump -C | head -n 10


00000000  31 36 09 32 20 50 69 73  74 6f 6c 73 20 46 74 2e  |16.2 Pistols Ft.|
00000010  20 54 2d 50 61 69 6e 20  26 20 54 61 79 20 44 69  | T-Pain & Tay Di|
00000020  7a 6d 2f 33 30 34 09 41  63 65 20 41 74 6b 69 6e  |zm/304.Ace Atkin|
00000030  73 2f 38 09 41 69 72 6d  61 74 65 20 66 65 61 74  |s/8.Airmate feat|
00000040  2e 20 4d 61 72 69 73 68  6b 61 20 50 68 69 6c 6c  |. Marishka Phill|
00000050  69 70 73 2f 31 36 09 41  6c 65 78 61 6e 64 65 72  |ips/16.Alexander|
00000060  20 4b 6f 77 61 6c 73 6b  69 20 66 65 61 74 2e 20  | Kowalski feat. |
00000070  42 61 72 63 61 20 42 61  78 61 6e 74 2f 35 34 34  |Barca Baxant/544|
00000080  09 41 6e 64 72 65 cc 81  73 20 66 65 61 74 20 44  |.Andre..s feat D|
00000090  4a 20 4d 69 6e 78 2f 31  36 09 41 73 69 61 20 43  |J Minx/16.Asia C|
```

the output of

```
du -sk * | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }; { if($1 < 1000) print $2 }'
```

is something like:

```
dirname
other dirname
other dirname with special chars / . - +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with [**whitequark's** answer](https://superuser.com/questions/152329/delete-directories-smaller-than-x/152333#152333) is that `grep` is adding nulls, but `awk` is taking them away. Also, you may want to restrict your `du` command to directories-only since that is what you say you want to measure and delete based on size. Adding a slash after the asterisk does this.

```
du -sk */ | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }; { if($1 < 1000) printf "%s\0",$2 }' | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: now I get:
 File name too long

when I pipe the output of 
du -sk */ | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }; { if($1 < 1000) printf "%s\0",$2 }'

the file has 1 line with more than 5000 chars.

Comment: @harp: What does `du -sk */ | wc -L` tell you?

Comment: du -sk */ | wc -l = 6250

Comment: @harp: No, a capital "L".

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: usage: wc [-clmw] [file ...]

no output

Comment: @harp: Try this: `du -sk */ | awk '{if (length($0) > max) max = length($0)} END {print max}'`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: 103

Comment: @harp: That's the maximum length of the directory names that you're trying to delete (although for that test, the > 1000 KB ones weren't excluded). The `printf` in my answer terminates each directory name with a null character before passing it to `xargs` where the `-0` (hyphen-zero) causes it to recognize that terminator. In an earlier comment, you said "when I pipe the output...the file has 1 line with more than 5000 chars". The command in my answer is not intended to be broken apart and redirected (I think that's what you mean instead of "piped") to a file. It's meant to use intact.

Comment: @harp: I forgot to say "so you shouldn't be getting "file name too long" errors at the end of the first sentence in my previous comment.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Ok I understand now that 
du -sk */ | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }; { if($1 < 1000) printf "%s\0",$2 }' is not intended to be piped to a file.  
But why does xargs not recognize the 0-terminator? Would it make sense to use another terminator?

Comment: @harp: Not "piped" to a file, "redirected". Pipes use `|`, redirections use `>`, `<` and `>>`, etc. I just checked the OS X man page for `xargs` and the `-0` option is supported. Please edit your question to add the output of `du -sk */ | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }; { if($1 < 1000) printf "%s\0",$0 }' | sort -nrz | hexdump -C | head -n 10`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: done

Comment: @all: there are no '00's in the output, and while command works as intended on my machine, I can only suppose that OS X `sort` eats `\0`s in *input* as well as `awk`.

Comment: @whitequark: The `-z` option to `sort` is supposed to handle nulls in input. @harp: Try `awk 'BEGIN {printf "\0"}' | hexdump -e '"%02x\n"'`. Do you get a "00"?

Comment: @Dennis: as I said, on my system it works as intended, but I do not see any nuls in OP's listing.

Comment: @Dennis: I get nothing.

Comment: @harp: My next suggestion is to try **whitequark's** main answer, but leave out the `grep '' -Z | ` and remove the `-0` from `xargs`.

Comment: @Dennis: du -sk * | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }; { if($1 < 1000) print $2 }'| xargs -s 1024 rm -rf
xargs: unterminated quote

Comment: @harp: Install GNU coreutils and use `gawk` (instead of `awk`) with my original answer.

Comment: @harp: Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `du -sk * | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }; { if($1 < 1000) print $2 }' | grep '' -Z | xargs -0 -s 1024 rm -rf`. Be careful with `rm`!

Comment: If you don't have a ton of directories to delete, I would throw on a "-i" which will make rm ask you if each directory is okay to delete before deleting it.

Comment: @Dan: if you don't have a ton of them to delete, you'd rather delete them by hand... selecting them from sorted list of some GUI would be both easier and safer.

Comment: one problem here. when I enter 
du -sk * | awk '{ if($1 < 1000) print $2 }'

the output doesn't show the directory names correctly. I have directory names with spaces and special characters. 
So the command shows "dirname" instead of "dirname correct bla  bla".

Comment: Fixed that and updated answer.

Comment: thx whitequark. fantastic.

Comment: oh I get "xargs: unterminated quote"

Comment: try this way...

Comment: it concatenates all directories and outputs "file name too long".

Comment: wow, you've got a *plenty* of them. try with `-s` argument: now name  of a single dir must not exceed 1024 characters...

Comment: xargs: insufficient space for argument

Comment: so you have a directory which name is bigger than 1k. leaving apart *why* would you need that, try increasing the `-s` option argument. on recent Linux the absolute limit would be ca. 200k.

Comment: I increased to 10000 but I still get "file name too long". Here is part of the output:

LeToya Luckett\nWideboys and Vula\nWriters Block\nY@k Ballz\nYahel\nYesterday's New Quintet\nYesterdays New Quintet\nYung Joc feat. Traeyon\nZenzile\n[01] Domina\n_Amy Winehouse\nfunkstörung\nmum\nsort_dir.txt\nsort_dir_kb.txt\nsubluna\n: File name too long

I really don't know why the directory name is bigger than 1k. Maybe it has something to do with OSX Server?

Comment: Ahem... I edited answer again, if that still would not work, can you please post output of `awk` to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)? I'll check it more deeply.

Comment: Ok, so everything is solved. Sorry for the timezone difference :)

Comment: @whitequark: it is still not working. see output in my updated question

Answer (score 1):

The "grep '' -Z" doesn't work for me, but tr does:

`du -sk * | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }; { if($1 < 10) print $2 }' |tr '\n' '\0' |xargs -0 rm -rf`

Answer (score 0):

The following what autogenerated by GitHub copilot

```bash
#!/bin/env bash

# recursively list all directories and their size with less than 10KB
find . -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' dir; do
    if [ $(du -s "$dir" | cut -f1) -lt 10 ]; then
        du -sh "$dir"
    fi
done

# ask for confirmation whether to delete the directories
read -p "Delete the above directories? [y/N] " -n 1 -r

# if yes, delete the directories
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    find . -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' dir; do
        if [ $(du -s "$dir" | cut -f1) -lt 10 ]; then
            rm -rf "$dir"
            echo "Deleted $dir"
        fi
    done
else # else, do nothing
    echo "Nothing deleted."
    exit 0
fi
```